# Using vue-router, why does my component not load

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Why wont my component load?

The root url

> http://localhost:8080/

must just show Bar?

Thanks for the help

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Home from './components/Home'
import Contact from '././components/Contact'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const Bar = { template: '<div>bar</div>' }

const routers = [
  { path: '/', component: Bar },
];

let router = new VueRouter({mode: 'history', routes: routers});

new Vue({
  router
}).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: did you have errors in browser console?

Answer (score 0):

Possible reasons are

1. You didn't import router properly in your code
2. You don't `Vue.use(VueRouter)`, just pass it to your new Vue object parameters

Correct it like so

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import VueRouter from 'router'
import Home from './components/Home'
import Contact from '././components/Contact'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

const Bar = { template: '<div>bar</div>' }

const routers = [
  { path: '/', component: Bar },
];

let router = new VueRouter({mode: 'history', routes: routers});

new Vue({
  router
}).$mount('#app')
```

it should work if your App.vue (imported on line 2) has `<router-view />` component in its template and all other imports are valid.